# SQL Server space in MDF file with multiple files and one Primary file

Tags: sql-server

We have space issues in our F: and our H: drive. We have added one more drive - I: drive with 500 GB capacity. Can we add the new database file in the I: drive and set the autogrowth option in the F: drive and the H: drive so that the new data will use the I: drive?

The current database files are as follows:

```
F:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf
G:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\test1_log.ldf
H:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\test123_1.ndf
H:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\test_2.ndf
```

Comment: New data go to the H drive? Do you mean the additional I drive?

Comment: I guess your question should read: _Can we add the new MDF file in the I drive and set the autogrowth option in the F drive and the H Drive so that the new data will use the **I** drive?_

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go ahead with that.

Limit the other secondary files (Disable Autogrowth) and create new ndf file in the new drive. This will resolve your space issue.

Answer (score -2):

**Disable Autogrowth on Existing Secondary Files**

Limit Growth on F: and H: Drives: To prevent the files on F: and H: drives from growing and consuming further space, disable the autogrowth setting for the database files (test123_1.ndf and test_2.ndf) located in these drives.
Manual Monitoring: With autogrowth disabled, it’s important to monitor these drives manually to avoid filling them up to their capacity, which could potentially lead to database issues.

**Step 2: Add a New Database File on the I: Drive**

Creating a New ndf File: Add a new ndf file on the I: drive with sufficient initial size to accommodate future data growth.
Setting Autogrowth: Configure the new ndf file with an autogrowth setting to allow it to grow automatically as data is added, ensuring that it uses the available space efficiently on the I: drive.

**Database Maintenance and Optimization**
Database Maintenance: Perform regular database maintenance tasks, such as updating statistics and optimizing indexes, to ensure the database performs optimally with the new file configuration.
Data Transfer: Consider redistributing data more evenly across all files, including the new file on the I: drive, to ensure balanced I/O and optimized performance.

**Regular Monitoring and Alerts**
Space Utilization: Implement regular monitoring to keep an eye on the space utilization of all your database files and take timely actions as needed.
Alerts: Set up alerts to notify the DBA or the support team in case of space issues, ensuring prompt intervention to prevent potential problems.

**Backup Strategy**
Backup: Adjust your backup strategy to include the new database file in the I: drive, ensuring all data is backed up properly.
Recovery Plan: Have a recovery plan in place, making sure you can restore the database correctly using the backups, including the new file on the I: drive.

Comment: The mechanism to redistribute data across files in a filegroup is to rebuild tables or indexes.